# Arduino code uploads fine, however avrdude output is not able to read / verify memory

Tags: arduino, atmega

Purchased some clone Arduino nanos a while ago and finally got to working with them. 
Of the 3 i worked with, 2 of them upload and verify fine.
The third is able to upload (code functions properly), however it fails to read flash data.

```
this is required to post pastebin
```

Here is the output from a clone that worked:
https://pastebin.com/x1y0yr1k

Here is the output from the one with the issue:
https://pastebin.com/YGAGC4XN

```
this is required to post pastebin
```

What I've done so far:

- Reflashed bootloader from working Arduino as ISP
- CH340 driver installed
- Used (old) bootloader when uploading
- Tested on both Linux and OSX

Any suggestions or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should ask your question on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working UNO or similar board, you could try uploading the bootloader using the Arduino IDE (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), and see if you get different results.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with using avrdude.

The link on sparkfun gives really good instructions on how to accomplish this task.  Scroll about half-way down to where it says **Upload Arduino as ISP**  https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader/all

Basically, you connect the UNO to your target as shown in the link, then select ArduinoISP in the examples menu, select the COM port and board, and upload the sketch.  Then you select your target board in tools, and select Programmer, Arduino as ISP in tools, and finally, Burn Bootloader in tools.

I've had 100% success burning blank Atmega chips using this method.